# Get text from an URL

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-lion

I want to get the plain text (that eventually is shown to the user) from an URL. I know how to extract all the contents, but what I get is all this html stuff, hidden stuff etc.
I just wat the plain text, without layout. Not really stripped all html tags from the content, but kind of parsed, and then without the layout. Firstly for comparison with other text and secondly to display it.

Is there any easy way to do this? (any existing code?)

Comment: Do you control the web server you're accessing the content from?

Comment: No, I don't control the web server. In fact, it are every time different web servers.

Comment: Do you _have_ to write code for this? i.e., are you writing an application that needs this functionality?

Comment: I need to give a percentage from a comparison between two texts...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the DOM.

First, load the resource into a [WebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebView_Class/). You don't need to put it into a window.

Then, [after it finishes loading](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebFrameLoadDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/webView%3adidFinishLoadForFrame%3a), ask for [the view's `mainFrameDocument`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WebView/mainFrameDocument), then ask the document for [its `documentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.documentElement), then ask *that* for [its `textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.textContent).

Comment: …and bear in mind that this will give you all textual content, not necessarily the content you want.

Comment: Yup. The `textContent` documentation mentions that it includes `style` and `script` elements. You can probably make a good whack at trimming that down by drilling down to the `body` element and getting the `textContent` from that, and you may want to delete any unwanted elements first. Fortunately, you'll have the whole DOM tree in your hands, so this is all quite possible and not terribly hard.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **readability** to extract the content.
I do not know if there is Obj-C version but you can use javascript one with `[yourWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"readability_js_code"]`

If you are retrieving the content (html) of the page not via UIWebView (ASIHTTP or custom code), try parsing with XML Parser ([NSXMLParser](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for example)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: UIWebView doesn't exist on the Mac.